Connect to a Private SQL Always On Availability group listener with Azure App
We have a fairly standard Azure Webapp - connecting via public IP to a database server which is a VM hosted in Azure.  NSG rules etc limit the traffic between the two.  The VM hosting the database is part of a private domain, but the webapp access is fine as the VM is assigned a Public IP.
Now I'd like to add high availability to this solution.  I have an Always On Availability group configured across two subnets, a listener is in place.  The listener works perfectly if I am connecting from within the network, but I'm unsure what's needed to make this available to an Azure webapp.
I had hoped there was a simple way of saying this Public IP points to this named object(the listener) within my private domain, but I can't see how I would do that.  Can anyone point me in the right direction here.
Domain Servers:
SQL1A, SQL1B - SQLdatabase servers with private IP's only
DC1,DC2 - Domain controllers and DNS servers
App1 - Azure webapp

I've been able to achieve this with Hybrid Connections, using the listener Name as the connection, but it seems to be very slow and often fails.  I'm not convinced it's checking for the primary server so much as choosing one at random.  Still looking for better options.
